# C file not showing in code hinting

Tags: iphone, c, xcode

I've got an iphone project that I've added a .c file and corresponding .h file.

In my app delegate I do the normal #include "MyCfile.h".

But when I try to create a variable of type "MyCfile" it doesnt appear in the code hinting. It's almost like xcode doesnt know it's there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an actual class or struct named MyCfile ? Just having a source file by this name doesn't do anything; you didn't mention a class so I'm going to assume you just haven't defined one in that header file.

Comment: I have 2 files that I've added to the project, MyCfile.h and MyCfile.c. Should I just write the c code in a regular .m file ?

Comment: You didn't answer my question -- did you define a type of any kind named "MyCfile" ? If not, then there's nothing for the auto-completer to complete.

Comment: O.k , I'm sorry I dont understand what you mean exactly by define a type. My c experience is minimal

Comment: You are trying to make a variable whose type is `MyCfile.` Because there's no such type built into the language, you would have to have defined one -- for instance, `class MyCfile { ... }` or `struct MyCfile {...}` or `enum MyCfile { ... }` or even `typedef int MyCfile`. Unless you've defined some data type by that name, there's nothing to complete. The file name is completely immaterial here.

Comment: for the record I made MyCfile a .m file and put the c functions in there